# Adding http headers to sunspot rails request

Tags: sunspot-rails, websolr

We are using sunspot-rails to connect to websolr. I am trying to find out a way to add http headers to the outgoing request. The samples are present only for rsolr but not for sunspot-rails.(https://github.com/onemorecloud/websolr-demo-advanced-auth).

The purpose is to use the headers for authentication.Is there a way to add/modify http headers from sunspot-rails for both indexing and querying calls?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ruby-sunspot/authentication/ruby-sunspot/-FtTQdg4czs/mvOuB7g8yCgJ

The example quoted by outoftime in this would be the solution to retrieve the http object.

```
class SolrConnectionFactoryWithTimeout
  def initialize(timeout = 60)
    @timeout = timeout
  end

  def connect(opts = {})
    client = RSolr.connect(opts)
    solr_connection = client.connection
    http = solr_connection.connection
    http.read_timeout = @timeout
    client
  end
end

Sunspot::Session.connection_class =
SolrConnectionFactoryWithTimeout.new(timeout.to_f)
```

Then use in combination with
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Setting+Headers

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['If-Modified-Since'] = file.mtime.rfc2822
```